# Get featured image url - from external website

Tags: wordpress, rss-reader

Building a custom RSS reader (in C#, but the server technology here is not relevant).

Since most of the sources of this RSS reader are WordPress posts, I would like to find a way to obtain the URL of the these sites posts featured images.

Most of the data related to WP featured images refers to WP plugins which are not relevant here (since I will need to get the data from external websites).

Is there a way to obtain the WP post featured image of an external website using either C# or any js library.

I'm sure it is possible, because RSS readers are already doing so (e.g. Feedly).

Answer (score 0):

There are many plugins to do that.

Here you are [one](https://wordpress.org/plugins/featured-images-for-rss-feeds/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Guess my question was not clear enough - I will need to read the featured image not from within WP but from an external app.
WP plugins are not useful in this case.